# avoid the other button from gettting affected when hovering over the button in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I have 2 `buttons` and a `container` surrounding them. made that container have a display of `flex` and centered the two buttons in the middle of the `div`. when I hover over one of them. the other changes slightly as well. How can I avoid this? I know that the issue is from `display: flex;` because it does what I want when I remove it. But I need to keep the elements centered,

```css
.two-buttons-container {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.button {
  font-size: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2vh;
}

.search-button {
  margin-right: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.lucky-button {
  margin-left: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.search-button:hover {
  border: 1.5px solid lightgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.lucky-button:hover {
  border: 1.5px solid lightgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="two-buttons-container">
  <button type="submit" class="button search-button">Google Search</button>
  <form action="https://www.google.com/doodles"><button type="submit" class="button lucky-button">I'm feeling lucky</button></form>
</div>
```

Comment: please embed your code to a compiler so, we can run and easly answer your quesion.

Comment: @gsharew That is a very strange way of saying "please create a runable snippet".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, hovering your buttons affects the dimensions of the button being hovered, because that border is only *added* to the button on hover.

To solve this, simply give your buttons an initial border with color `transparent`, so the border is already there before hovering.

```css
border: 1.5px solid transparent;
```

On `:hover` then, all you need to change is the `border-color`:

```css
.search-button:hover,
.lucky-button:hover {
  border-color: lightgray;
}
```

```css
.two-buttons-container {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.button {
  font-size: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
  border: 1.5px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2vh;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.search-button {
  margin-right: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.lucky-button {
  margin-left: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.search-button:hover,
.lucky-button:hover {
  border-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="two-buttons-container">
  <button type="submit" class="button search-button">Google Search</button>
  <form action="https://www.google.com/doodles"><button type="submit" class="button lucky-button">I'm feeling lucky</button></form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.two-buttons-container {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.button {
  font-size: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2vh;
}

.search-button {
  border: 1.5px solid transparent;
  margin-right: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.lucky-button {
  border: 1.5px solid transparent;
  margin-left: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.search-button:hover {
  border: 1.5px solid lightgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.lucky-button:hover {
  border: 1.5px solid lightgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="two-buttons-container">
  <button type="submit" class="button search-button">Google Search</button>
  <form action="https://www.google.com/doodles"><button type="submit" class="button lucky-button">I'm feeling lucky</button></form>
</div>
```

Just add this in button CSS

```
border: 1.5px solid transparent;
```

Comment: thanks it worked! may I know what that line did?

Comment: @Ahmad That is why code-only answers are almost never good answers. See my answer for an explanation. Answers should not only be judged based on whether "it works", but also - and mainly - on how it helps understanding the problem, and the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your default button style has no border. When the hover button gets some border and it gets more space, you can solve this problem. just use **defult button css**,

```
.search-button {
  margin-right: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 100%;
    border: 1.5px solid transparent;
}

.lucky-button {
  margin-left: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1.5px solid transparent;
}
```

just put the css it will work, as you want. :)